# Error appears when installing python packages: pythonw not found

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, python-packaging

after trying to update Anaconda using conda update --all, the downloading successfully ends but when trying to install the packages, the error message:
" Windows cannot find 'pythonw'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again " appears. anyone knows how to deal with it?
thanks in advance

P.S. I installed Anaconda somewhere other that C:\, might have something to do with that? Environment variables?

Comment: have you updated environment path ?

Comment: Yeah I had to, I added Anaconda/Scripts , it didn't recognize "conda" before

Comment: open command prompt type `cd c:\Python27\ ` and then check with  `pythonw.exe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem and I do have Anaconda installed for all users (Win7-x86). It may indicate that all/single user installation is not an issue. I start update using full path to python.exe and the only environment variable PYTHONHOME with actual path to Anaconda installation. No any addition to the system PATH environment variable, since it is NOT a recommended option in Miniconda installer. I have my own simple py.bat, where PYTHONHOME is set and python.exe started using full path. I use following command line (all arguments after py passed to python.exe):

```
 py -m conda update --all
```

I do have mentioned message about PythonW not found, but everything is installed somehow. Possible problem can be with adding shortcuts to Windows menu: I did review sources and I found suspicious place in Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\menuinst folder, __init__.py file. I did modify single line in the install() function, call to RunAsAdmin(). Instead of using simple "pythonw" - I did replace it with full path to pythonw.exe. No more any problem with installations or updates for me. I did create issue in

```
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/menuinst/issues/64
```

It looks like nobody going to fix Anaconda (as of today, APR08-2018), but you can find in this issue description more info how to fix your own local installation (as I did already). If fix is working or not working for you - you can add comments to the issue. If it happen that issue already fixed - you may need to update "conda" package.

Comment: Package "menuinst" update was published about MAY-30-2018. There is no more problem with "PythonW.exe not found" for two reasons: they use now Python.exe instead PythonW.exe and also explicitly use full path to Python installation folder. Everything is going to work with or without Python installation on the system PATH environment variable. Mentioned issue 64 is closed now, see for more details in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

The error is typical because python by default is installed only for current user . During python installation with little effort from our side i.e to change the installation to all users will get rid of this error.

In conjunction to the above step the environment variable needs to updated to the installed location.

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to update Anaconda after installation. In the Anaconda Powershell Prompt type:

```
conda update conda
```